# In iOS can a cell in a tableview have more than just a text

Tags: ios, tableview

Can i have two images and a few text labels in a cell of a tableView ? All dynamically assigned ?

Comment: Yes. You can put anything you want in a table cell. Read the "Table View Programming For iOS" for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the documentation for the UITableViewCell class, specifically the UITableViewCellStyle constants which allow for various types of standard table cells to be created.  If the built in styles do not meet your requirements, you can subclass UITableViewCell and create anything you want, since it's just another type of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can! There are several ways of achieving that, the most popular being subclass the `UITableViewCell` class, and creating your own custom cell, and you can have whatever you want in it. But just to get an idea of how to go about doing that, I suggest you go through the following links:

- [Table View Programming Guide for iOS - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)
- [Crafting Custom
  UITableViewCells - MobileTuts+](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/?search_index=6)